# Regex - Escaping square brackets along with boundry

Tags: php, regex

I have a website where users can have custom actions when a keyword is detected in a sentence. How I currently do matches is like the following:

```
$output = array();
preg_match('/\b' . $keyword . '\b/', $phrase, $output);
```

If I find a match `if(count($output) > 0) {` then the custom action is ran. This is for spoken sentences so it is for things like operator, we have a custom one called [silence] so when silence is detected it runs an action.

However when the keyword contains brackets for example: [silence] the regex fails because it has square brackets. I have tried escaping both like `\b\[silence\]\b` However this does not detect a match.

Also this is in PHP

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

The "word boundary" expression matches if the next character is a part of a word, and `[`  isn't (it is not a letter)

From [Regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) :

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
>
> Simply put: \b allows you to perform a “whole words only” search using a regular expression in the form of \bword\b. A “word character” is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not “word characters” are “non-word characters”.

So you need to "rewrite" the `\b` expression that can suit your need, like :

```
(?<=[\s\.,;])\[silence\](?=[\s\.,;])
```

First, a non-matching "delimiter character" (space, dot, comma, ... You probably need to add a few more), followed by your expression, followed by a non-matching delimiter character again.